# MVVM Data Update

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, binding

I recently downloaded the MahApps.Metro package to play around with there Metro Design and the MVVM.
In there project they create the ViewModel:

```
DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(Dispatcher);
```

which looks like this:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

    public bool Busy { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        Busy = true;
        _dispatcher = dispatcher;

        var wc2 = new WebClient();
        wc2.DownloadStringCompleted += WcDownloadStringCompleted2;
        wc2.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gethypedtracks&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json"));
    }

    private void WcDownloadStringCompleted2(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrackWrapper>(e.Result);
            _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                                   {
                                                       Busy = false;
                                                   }));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I cut out a few parts, but the code is working like it is shown here. So they basically they create a thread and before the thread ends, they set the Busy-Property to false (no events were fired).
In XAML they bound this property to an busy-indicator:

```
<Controls:ProgressRing IsActive="{Binding Busy}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Everything is working fine, the control changes as the Property does.
But now I wanted to copy this for the beginning. XAML and setting the DataContext is equal.
My ViewModel looks like this (VB this time, but should not make the difference):

```
Public Class testmodel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private _busy As Boolean = True
Public Sub New(dispatcher As Windows.Threading.Dispatcher)
    Dim t1 As Thread = New Thread(Sub()
                                      'Emulate Progress
                                      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
                                      dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub()
                                                                            Busy = False
                                                                        End Sub))

                                  End Sub)
    t1.Start()
End Sub

Public Property Busy As Boolean
    Get
        Return _busy
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        NotifyPropertyChanged(Nothing)
        _busy = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(info As [String])
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
```

End Class

So I create a new thread, stop it for 2 seconds and then change the Busy-Property. First I didn't fire an event (as the original one), but nothing happens. Then I added the line to fire the event, but nothing happens again.
Am I overseeing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you're notifying your property change before setting the value.  Also, your property change is sending Nothing.  Without sending the name as the argument, there is no indication of which property was updated.

```
Public Property Busy As Boolean
    Get
        Return _busy
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)            
        _busy = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Busy")
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Not sending the property name is perfectly valid, it means all properties should be reread, rather than just the "Busy" property. But your first sentence seems like the right answer to me.

Comment: Ah, thank you, the order was the solution. Btw you can use null/nothing - it causes to update all properties. But do you have an idea why it works on the C# project without an event?

Comment: Hmm...Not sure.  I haven't done any Metro programming yet; I'm still in .NET 4.0 land.